# Gii: generate CRUD application from existing database tables?

Tags: yii, gii

I have a mysql database with tables that have one to many relationships with foreign keys linking them.

How can I use gii to create CRUD form pages which will reflect the table relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at the following article which includes using yii's gii

[Creating Your First Yii Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app)

Comment: it seems like I need to do this for each table, is there a way to generate it from the mysql schema?

Comment: You can do in 5 minutes all of them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qX98YK_RnPU also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164733/does-gii-automatically-create-relations-for-generated-models?rq=1